# Access stored procedure using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

How can I execute a stored procedure from Linq-to-SQL in an efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: All the images in the link are dead making it useless.