# Fastest way to find 300K record exist in database or not

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

I have a situation in where I have two database one is oracle database and the other is sql server. In oracle I have at least 300K, and in sql server I have 400K record. I want to check if oracle data exist in sql server or not. I tried to use for each method in where I check every record in oracle if exist in sql server and this took long time. I am asking you if there another method to that will give me the same result. I am using LINQ for the queries

```
                conn.Open();

                cmd = new OdbcCommand()

                {

                    Connection = conn,

                    CommandText = "select c_id, c_name,c_dob,c_email,c_pnumber from customers"

                    CommandType = CommandType.Text

                };

            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (dr.Read())

            {

           var customers = _db.tblCustomers.FirstOrDefaulst(x 
           =>x.C_ID.Equals(dr.GetValue(0)) 

          if(customers !=null)
          {

          //do something

          }

          else
          {

          tblCustomers customer = new tblCustomers {


             C_name = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1)),
             C_dob = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(2)),
             C_email = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(3)),
             C_pnumber = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(4))
            }
          }

         }
```

P.S : This is just for adding new customer , but I have another code with same logic for updating records and i should run these methods every day

Query for adding new record

```
var customers = _db.tblCustomers.FirstOrDefaulst(x 
               =>x.C_ID.Equals(dr.GetValue(0))
```

Query for updating an existing record

```
var customers = _db.tblCustomers.FirstOrDefaulst(x 
           =>x.C_ID.Equals(dr.GetValue(0)) && x.c_name == dr.GetValue(1) )
```

Comment: Load all of the records in both databases (even if just in temp table). Do a join.

Comment: It looks like you're comparing just the ID of the records. If thats correct, modify the SQL statement to return just the ID, put all IDs of the oracle DB in a C# HashSet and then iterate the MSSQL result and check if the ID is in the HashSet you've created from the Oracle DB

Comment: If you are able to manage the SQL server, consider adding the Oracle DB as a linked server. Then, the heavy lifting can be done by the DB instead of having to use C# code.

Comment: Just to add to @christoph's comment, if its possible then put the logic in a Stored procedure at the SQL Server side and then return a value from it which helps you to identify whether a record exists or not. Then just call the procedure using C#.

Comment: so do you mean i create a for loop to each record exist in oracle and i call a stored procedure that compare between the record if exist or not in the database ? so stored procedure will be called 300K times ?!

Comment: No don't call the procedure 300 times. The way I see it, just call the procedure once. There are 2 ways to accomplish this:- 1) Copy the Oracle data to SQL Server table and then use joins on common fields and return matching records 2) From SQL use Oracle as a linked server and then use joins and return matching records. See my Answer below. It's hard to write everything in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment the first method is recommended.

```
Select A.columns, B.columns from SQL_Table A INNER JOIN Oracle_TABLE B
ON A.common_column = B.common_column
```

-- if required records can be further filtered

```
and A.column = value  and  B.column = value
```

OR

You can use the oracle table via linked server but that might have a small impact on performance due to latency.

You can call the stored procedure using linq. See below Stackoverflow link.

[Access stored procedure using Linq-to-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540935/access-stored-procedure-using-linq-to-sql)

OR you can use ADO.NET to call a stored procedure.

---

per my comment use the below insert query.

```
INSERT INTO SQL_TABLE(write all the column names of 
  SQL_Table where you want to insert value from oracle table)
SELECT Distinct B.Columns from Oracle_TABLE B INNER JOIN SQL_TABLE A
ON A.common_column <> B.common_column
```

Comment: yes i got it . but how can i insert records that doesn't exist in sql server using this method ?

Comment: Assuming there are same number of columns in SQL and Oracle table, use the below insert query.

Comment: assume i have more columns in oracle table (that what i have )  than sql table ?!

Comment: I have modified my answer to answer your above comment. please note that in join I have used "<>"(Not equal to) instead of "=".

Comment: I have added the SQL Keyword "Distinct" in my answer to give only unique records. As an alternate you can also use group by. Test it first on some sample data to be sure.

Comment: thank you so much . Tomorrow  I will try your answer and I will give you my feedback

Answer (score 0):

Upon thinking out loud, I think it would make more sense to use the below subquery in your stored procedure instead of using Joins and its also more efficient this way. We use joins usually with a equal to sign(=) and not the other way around(<>). It is a standard practice :). 
Assuming there is a common column in both the tables (SQL and Oracle)with unique values, use the below subquery syntax.It will easily add the missing records in SQL table from Oracle Table.
Let me know if you want a detailed explanation of the Query.

```
INSERT INTO SQL_Table(write all the column names of SQL_Table where you want values)
Select B.columns from Oracle_Table B where B.common_unique_column NOT IN (select A.common_unique_column from SQL_TABLE A)
```

Comment: Again, try it with some sample data first :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this
1.first get a specific item as list that is match with SQL Data for Oracle data
2.Match oracle data with sql data using `Contains()` function and get a data list that match with sql data...

Select a column data to make list from both table that must have in the both table

Sample code bellow

```
var oracleCustomerList=_db.tblCustomers.Select(m=>m.coustomerName).ToList();
var sqlCustomerList=db.tblCustomers.Where(x=>oracleCustomerList.Contains(n=>n.coustomerName)).ToList();
```